# I have 6 fields in a form and each field is an array of same length field1[], field2[] and so on. How can I insert multiple rows into a word template

Tags: ms-word, phpword

```
$staffRowCount = count($_POST['staff_discipline']);
for ($i = 0; $i < $staffRowCount; $i++) {
        $replacements = array('staff_discipline' => $_POST['staff_discipline'][$i]);
        $replacements1 = array('staff_contractor' => $_POST['staff_contractor'][$i]);
        $replacements2 = array('staff_name' => $_POST['staff_name'][$i]);
        $replacements3 = array('staff_email' => $_POST['staff_email'][$i]);
        $replacements4 = array('staff_job_title' => $_POST['staff_job_title'][$i]);
        $replacements5 = array('staff_date' => $_POST['staff_date'][$i]);
    }
        $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('block1',$staffRowCount,true,false, $replacements);
        $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('block2',$staffRowCount,true,false, $replacements1);
        $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('block3',$staffRowCount,true,false, $replacements2);
        $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('block4',$staffRowCount,true,false, $replacements3);
        $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('block5',$staffRowCount,true,false, $replacements4);
        $templateProcessor->cloneBlock('block6',$staffRowCount,true,false, $replacements5);
```

these are the placeholders I'm using in template. I have put each placeholder within ${block} ${/block} as follows.

${block1}${staff_discipline}${/block1}, ${block2}${staff_contractor}${/block2}, ${block3}${staff_name}${/block3}, ${block4}${staff_email}${/block4}, ${block5}${staff_job_title}${/block5}, ${block6}${staff_date}${/block6}

when I'am executing the script it shows large binary text which includes so many symbols and word file not being created. what am I doing wrong? please help me with it. thankyou

I have tried CloneRowAndSetValues method, I have also looped through SetValues method but every time there occurred fetal error. I have tried the following approach as well.
//for loop starts here.

```
$values[] = array( ['staff_discipline' => $_POST['staff_discipline'][$i],
                     'staff_contractor' => $_POST['staff_contractor'][$i],
                     'staff_name' => $_POST['staff_name'][$i],
                     'staff_email' => $_POST['staff_email'][$i],
                     'staff_job_title' => $_POST['staff_job_title'][$i],
                     'staff_date' => $_POST['staff_date'][$i]
                 ]);
//for loop ends here.
$templateProcessor->cloneRowAndSetValues('staff_row', $values);
```